# How to bind a property of external control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I've a `ToggleButton` control that I've inserted in my `Grid` in this way:

```
xmlns:LSControls="clr-namespace:LS"
```

and then:

```
<LSControls:Favourite />
```

What I need to do is bind the `IsSelected` property of each item of `ListView`, infact I've inserted the control inside a ListView like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="AllMatches" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" SelectionChanged="AllMatches_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
           <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <LSControls:Favourite />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

this will display the control in eac item of my `ListView`, but I need to check or uncheck the `ToggleButton` based on the value of `IsSelected`, this property is available for each item of `AllMatches` source.

How can do this?

The structure of the control is like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Star" UriSource="add-favourite.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="StarEmpty" UriSource="add-favourite-empty.png" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ToggleButton Focusable="False" Width="19" Height="19">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border>
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"                                                  
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                                        <Condition Binding = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource StarEmpty}"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Add to favourite."/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource Star}"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Remove from Favourite."/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So your UserControl is just a Grid with a single ToggleButton child with a Style? Why not derive a custom control from ToggleButton?

Comment: @Clemens you mean customize the toggle button? I need to have a user control like my own 'cause I need to implement it in different windows

Comment: As said, I mean deriving a custom control from ToggleButton. See the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @Clemens no way to a binding on the usercontrol?

Comment: Sure, create a dependency property `IsSelected` in your `Favourite` class, then bind the ToggleButton's IsSelected property to that of the UserControl like `IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.